# How to CLI docker container?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I used Docker Containers with AWS EC2 to run a database and an app. Both containers are up & running.
How to CLI to the app? I wanted to access the web server folders. When I ran locally using Docker Desktop GUI it gives an icon to CLI for each container.

I issued an ifconfig command and converted the inet6 address to ipv4. I tried the ip via putty, it says server is not reachable. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "CLI", what specific action are you trying to perform?  If Docker wasn't involved, how would you do this particular thing?  (You wouldn't typically try to get an interactive shell inside an Nginx reverse proxy, for example.)  Can you provide an [mcve] demonstrating the specific issue you're having, and describing how you're building the images and launching the containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to your docker instance. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance-connect.html) is the official page to do it. (Here you might want to use SSH).

To connect to the containers, first list them:

```
docker ps
```

then open a console in the container you need

```
docker exec -ti <container-id> sh
```